# .NET Compute node in IBM WebSphere Message Broker V7

Tags: .net, websphere, messagebroker

I am trying to integrate with IBM WebSphere Message Broker V7 from .NET.
In version 8 there is a .NET Compute Node but I don't find it in V7.
Are there any other options?

Thanks in advance,
Radu

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The .NET compute node was only introduced in version 8 (see: http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wmbhelp/v8r0m0/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.etools.mft.doc%2Fbb23110_.htm)

In order to call .NET from a v7 broker you would need to write a C layer to provide a bridge in a C UDN which would involve using the CLR hosting APIs to call into a .NET assembly.

I wouldn't recommend both due to the amount of effort involved and because coding C UDN's opens yourself up to abending the broker if you make mistakes.

Comment: thanks. i'll use the WebSphere Queue as a bridge to my .NET app.